# DRF how to update email with @action?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

When I try to update my authenticated user but it's create new user. Where is problem?

**View**

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

**Action**

```
@action(methods=['PATCH'], detail=False)
        def change_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
            user = self.get_object()
            serializer = serializers.UserEmailSerializer(data=self.request.data, context={'request': self.request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            self.send_email(user.email)
            return Response({'Confirm yours new email'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Serilializer for action**

```
class UserEmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```